# How can I escape a death loop?

Tags: i-wanna-be-the-boshy

I've managed to have the game save while I'm right above a spike. Even if I jump before I die I can't get high enough to hit the save thing again. To the left and right of me there are just more spikes, making it impossible for me to escape this death loop. Is there a built-in way to fix this, or failing that, how could I use something like cheat engine to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you press <kbd>F3</kbd> and select another character, it will place you slightly different. I only got this to work with custom characters which are free to download though, but I don't know if there's some standard characters that also can do this. Keep in mind that custom characters often fire shots from different height. I was stuck inside a moving spike, and this worked for me. I used magic Mickey or something.

Answer (score 2):

I've never played this game, but I've researched others who have been in familiar predicaments like yours and have found a solution.

As soon as the game starts, press the console key (*~*), then type the following in the console:

> tgm

That will toggle god mode until you detoggle it. Do whatever you have to in order to get out of there. Then repeat the above steps to disable god mode.

If there are any more obstacles that face your way, tell me in the comments and I'll do my best to help you out.

Cheers!

Comment: This sounds so promising... but I *have* played the game, and I am unable to get the `~` key to open the console.

Answer (score 0):

I just got into this situation 5 minutes ago and found another possible solution. If the save box is really close by but you can't jump high enough to hit it, you can change your character to Ryu and which makes your shots bigger as well as slightly higher. Glad I don't have to replay the game.

Answer (score -3):

Spam the jump button and press restart. You can use cheat engine to slow the game and jump right before you die.

Comment: As I said above, "even if I jump before I die I can't get high enough to hit the save thing again, and to the left and right there are just more spikes."